# Не отображается контейнер Docker

Tags: docker

Первый раз работаю с Dockerom хочу организовать микросервисную архитектуру.
Файл marketplace.py

```
    # marketplace/marketplace.py

import os

from flask import Flask, render_template
import grpc


from recommendations_pb2 import BookCategory, RecommendationRequest
from recommendations_pb2_grpc import RecommendationsStub


app = Flask(__name__)

recommendations_host = os.getenv("RECOMMENDATIONS_HOST", "localhost")
recommendations_channel = grpc.insecure_channel(
    f"{recommendations_host}:50051"
)
recommendations_client = RecommendationsStub(recommendations_channel)


@app.route("/")
def render_homepage():
    recommendations_request = RecommendationRequest(
        user_id=1, category=BookCategory.SELF_HELP, max_results=4
    )
    recommendations_response = recommendations_client.Recommend(
        recommendations_request
    )
    return render_template(
        "homepage.html",
        recommendations=recommendations_response.recommendations,
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,threaded=True)
```

после чего запускаю контейнер

```
D:\WebService>docker run -p 127.0.0.1:5001:5001/tcp --network microservices -e
RECOMMENDATIONS_HOST=recommendations marketplace
```

В консоле выводит

```
* Serving Flask app "marketplace" (lazy loading) 
* Enviroment:production 
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
Use a production WSGI server instead.
Debug mode: off
Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Но при переходе по адресу "Не удается получить доступ к сайту"
Можете подсказать в какую сторону копать, заранее большое спасибо!.

Comment: не тот порт прокидываете (5000 vs 5001)

Comment: Спасибо сейчас попробую

Comment: Всеравно также выдает ошибку, я так понимаю прокидывать необходимо было здесь ? run -p 127.0.0.1:5000:5000/tcp